# Does this codes increase reference count?

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting

Does this codes increase reference count?

Q1. collectionView capture reference increase reference count and ViewController doesn't deinit?

```swift
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

 .do(onNext: { [collectionView] in
               guard let cv = collectionView else { return }
                self.collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = self.collectionView.bounds.width == $0.x
                })
```

Q2. pageScrollView increase reference count?

```
if let pageScrollView = self.pageViewController.view.subviews.filter ({ $0 is UIScrollView }).first as? UIScrollView {
            pageScrollView.rx.contentOffset
                .filter { [pageScrollView] _ in pageScrollView.isDragging }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to `filter(something).first`, you should `.lazy.filter(something).first`, to avoid the intermediate array allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Yes, you're explicitly making a strongly capturing reference to `collectionView`

Q2: Yes, you're making an implicit strongly capturing reference to `pageScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks, in Q1 case, the collectionView is defined weak var, so I think another case like ClassA and ClassB refer a weak variable does not increase reference count? does it?

Comment: @fadeguy Just because the object is weakly referenced in one place, doesn't effect the strong references to it. You're still making a strong reference.

Comment: Thank you again, I totally understand what you said.